# Selecting nth-child From parent id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have parent div id, this parent have 3 children, each child have their own children. This is tree like structure. What I want is select to select second child on level one.

currently i am doing like this

```
var Second_child = $('#Parent_id:nth-child(2)');
```

But it is not selecting the child. I don't want to use eq() function.

Comment: Show your html please.

Comment: `$('#Parent_id > *:nth-child(2)');`

Comment: @Satpal I think child selector is needed because of multiple levels else 2nd child from all levels will be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) here

```
var Second_child = $('#Parent_id > :nth-child(2)');
```

If you use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) 2nd child in every level will get selected

Your selector tries to find an element with id `Parent_id` which is the second child of its parent